# How to make classes inherit each other?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have two classes `ClassOne`, `ClassTwo` each one in a separated file `.h` and `.cpp` as follow:

```
// ClassOne.h file
#include <ClassTwo.h>
class ClassOne : public ClassTwo {
protected:
    type m_string; // Required for "ClassTwo"
}

// ClassTwo.h file
#include <ClassOne.h>
class ClassTwo : public ClassOne {
public:
    method1(); // <---|
    method2(); // <- Required to be available in class ClassOne.
    method3(); // <---|
}
```

As you saw in the previous code the two classes inherit each other, but that code occurs errors `error C2504: 'ClassOne': base class undefined` and `error C2504: 'ClassTwo': base class undefined`.

The purpose of that is I want the member's functions of "ClassTow" to be available in "ClassOne" but also "ClassTwo" needs a member variable in "ClassOne".

**How to make the two classes inherit from each other?**

Comment: You can't. C++ does not work this way. Otherwise, you have ClassOne containing ClassTwo, containing ClassOne, containing ClassTwo, all the way until this class inheritance consumes all molecules in the known universe. And you don't really want that to happen, do you?

Comment: That makes sense only if they are templates, and the actual specializations break the cycle dependency.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Can you problem be solved using CRTP?

Comment: `class X : public class Y` means a `Y` is an `X` with some extra stuff. It is not possible for an `X` to also be a `Y` with some extra stuff.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I did that because I want the member's functions of `ClassTow` to be available in `ClassOne` but also `ClassTwo` needs a member variable in `ClassOne`.

Comment: that sounds like you should have 1 class, not 2

Comment: @LionKing perhaps pass a pointer (or reference) to your `ClassOne` object in to your `ClassTwo` object's constructor, and have `ClassTwo` hold the pointer/reference to the `ClassOne` object as a member-variable?  Then each class-object can call methods on the other object via the member-variable it holds.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to decide how to structure your code properly with an actual concrete example. What *problem are you trying to solve* with this organization?

Comment: @LionKing Are you sure you don't want `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` to both inherit another common class instead?

Comment: Why not to use virtual methods with overrides?

Comment: @kmdreko: Each class for a different purpose from the other but there's a link between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the CRTP would solve your problem. First, create the class `ClassOne` as a template that uses a type `ClassTwo` as a parameter. This type shall be the class that inherits from `ClassOne`:

```
template<typename ClassTwo>
class ClassOne
{
public:
    void methodOne() {
        if (you need to use methods of ClassTwo) 
             static_cast<ClassTwo*>(this)->methodTwo();
    }
};
```

Then define `ClassTwo` as the one that inherits `ClassOne` specifying the template parameter with itself:

```
class ClassTwo : public ClassOne<ClassTwo>
{
public:
    void methodTwo() {
        if (you need to use methods of ClassOne) 
             methodOne();
    }
};
```

**Update:** that is a hard way to solve the problem. There are other even simpler ones, for example to use virtual methods:

```
class ClassOne
{
public:
    void methodOne() {
        if (you need to use methods of ClassTwo) 
             methodTwo();
    }
    virtual void methodTwo() = 0;
};

class ClassTwo : public ClassOne
{
public:
    void methodTwo() override {
        if (you need to use methods of ClassOne) 
             methodOne();
    }
};
```

Both approaches have their own pros and cons. We need to know your task in details to advise which one is better.

Comment: Although this works, I have a hard time imagining why someone would want a circular inheritance??

Comment: @YunfeiChen if we forget of the question itself and would try to avoid ProblemXY bias, the actual problem that the author has is "how to call methods of each other". That can be solved in many ways, for example using virtual functions. CRTP could be closer to what the author means.

Comment: The second way is fine but will make that class as an abstract class, right?

Comment: @LionKing, the class is abstract, but the object has to implement all the abstract methods. Isn't that what you need saying that `ClassOne` uses some methods of `ClassTwo`? You have to implement them, otherwise how to use?

Comment: Although that is not what I want exactly, but there is no solution but this. anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make classes inherit each other?

A class cannot possibly inherit its child. A base can only be specified in the class definition, and a class cannot be used as a base unless it has been specified. There is no way to order the two definitions in such way that both are before each other. Thus, this is not possible.

Such inheritance would also be paradoxical because a class object contains the base as a sub object within itself. As such, you would end in situation where there is One inside Two inside One inside Two inside One inside Two inside One inside Two inside One inside Two inside One inside Two inside ... can you see where this is going? It is going nowhere. The object is infinitely large because it contains infinitely deep inheritance hierarchy.

To express this in another way: Inheritance hierarchy can be seen as a directed graph. An inheritance hierarchy graph cannot contain a cycle.

---

> The purpose of that is I want the member's functions of "ClassTow" to be available in "ClassOne" but also "ClassTwo" needs a member variable in "ClassOne".

You can have two classes, both of which having access to all of the data members and the functions like this:

```
struct ClassOne {
    // all the member functions
    // all the data members
};

struct ClassTwo : ClassOne {
    // nothing here
};
```

Now you have two classes, both of which have access to the same data members and member functions.

Comment: "ClassTwo" needs a variable member found in "ClassOne", look at my code again.

Comment: @LionKing ClassTwo has that member variable in my example because it inherits it.

Comment: Sorry, "ClassTwo" inherits "ClassOne", then, the member variable will be available, but "ClassOne" doesn't inherit "ClassTwo", so, all members functions found in "ClassTwo" will be unavailable in "ClassOne".

Comment: @LionKing As per my advice, if you put all the member functions in ClassOne, and none in ClassTwo, then ClassTwo doesn't have any member functions that could be missing from ClassOne.